# How to insert batches using native queries

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an application written using spring data jpa.
I need to save to the database only those customers who are not there yet. For this I want to use a native query

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customers")
public class Customer {

  @Id
  private String customerId;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

//constructors, getters, setters
}

public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, String> {
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "INSERT into Customers (customerId, firstName, lastName)" +
            "values (:customerId, :firstName, :lastName)" +
            "ON CONFLICT (customerId) DO NOTHING", nativeQuery = true)
    void insert(@Param("customerId") String customerId, @Param("firstName")String firstName, @Param("lastName") String lastName);
}
```

. But now this implementation is slow - it takes almost a second for 50 records, although the parameters are enabled:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
```

Is it possible to somehow rewrite the query to pass a list to it?
Somehow so:

```
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "INSERT into Customers (customerId, firstName, lastName)" +
            "values (:customerId, :firstName, :lastName)" +
            "ON CONFLICT (customerId) DO NOTHING", nativeQuery = true)
    void batchInsertCustomer(List<Customer> customers);
```

Perhaps there is another way to save only those records that do not exist?
Perhaps there are other ways to speed up insert?
My key `customerId` is always full.

Comment: We decided to use JDBC template to speed up inserts and support multiple values:

`template.batchUpdate(INSERT_QUERY, records, records.size(),
            (ps, record) -> {
                ps.setObject(1, record.getUuid().getUuid(), Types.OTHER);
                ps.setString(2, record.getOtherParam());
    ...
            })`

But make sure you apply `reWriteBatchedInserts`.